# strict-origin-when-cross-origin when using POST in a form to a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I'm working though Greg Lims's book on Node.js, express & mongodb and I'm stuck at the bit when a form is used to send data to a route and the route will then just console out the body.title of the form. I get Status 404 Not Found. Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin. I need an education on CSP and CORS but don't know where to start?

my index.js and form.html
...

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = new express()
const cors = require('cors'); 
app.use(express.static('public'))
const path = require('path');
const { header } = require('express/lib/request');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })) 

app.use(cors({
  origin: "*",
  })
);



app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});









app.listen(4000,()=>{
  console.log('App listening on port 4000')
})

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('get root')
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,('pages/index.html')))
})

app.get('/about.html',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('get about')
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,('pages/about.html')))
}) 

app.get('/post.html',(req,res)=>{
  console.log('get post')
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,('pages/post.html')))
})  

app.get('/store',(req,res)=>{

  res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self', form-action 'self',script-src 'self'");
  console.log('store post')
  console.log(req)
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.title)
  res.redirect('/')
})

my form

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self', form-action 'self',script-src 'self'">
    
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Create</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <H1>Create Page</H1>
         
      <form action="/store" method="POST"> 
        <div class="control-group"> 
          <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls"> 
            <label>Title</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" name=”title” >  
                  </div>
                 </div> 
    
            </div>
             <br>          
             <div class="form-group"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
             </div> 
            </form> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
    </div>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'http://localhost'">
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'"> -->
    <hr>
    </body>
    </html>

...
```

Comment: `Referrer-Policy`, CORS, CSP, and 404 Not Found errors are four completely different things. (And they're all pretty well documented if you use a search engine).

Comment: Hello Quentin, thank you for taking the time to read my post and for your reply. I did research these issues and I did amend Mr. Lim's code to this effect but to no avail. Something about using POST makes the security go back to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a POST endpoint in your example, they are all `GET`. As far as I can tell from your `<form />`what you actually want is POST to `store`. If that's the case replace this bit

```
app.get('/store',(req,res)=>{

  res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self', form-action 'self',script-src 'self'");
  console.log('store post')
  console.log(req)
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.title)
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

for this bit. Notice I have only changed the HTTP verb.

```
app.post('/store',(req,res)=>{

  res.set("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self', form-action 'self',script-src 'self'");
  console.log('store post')
  console.log(req)
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.title)
  res.redirect('/')
})
```

Please read the [official docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) on basic routing on Express. That should give you some insight.

Comment: Oh thank you Jose. That's more like it.

Comment: Thank you José Henrique. That was it. It needed to be set to post.